# when loading the module ,i face a problem as it not being probe invoked succefully

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

when i loaded my module it is loaded and it is showing in lsmod but my probe function not invoking. I checked my dts file .compatible that matches correctly with my driver (.compatible) even though my probe not invoked

I am trying in beagelbone black .where i have an driver which is for uart and I configured the uart pin using my dtb file. When I inserted driver using insmod it invoking init function but by probe is not calling and device and my driver binding is not happeing

Comment: In the init you need to register with some bus to call you when a matching event should call your probe.  It sounds like you want `uart_register_driver(drv)` in your `init()`.  The 'drv' structure contains a name that uart subsystem will match to a DTS entry.